# CSRF Token mismatch in cookies and html

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, csrf-token

How can i retrieve the CSRF Token 'properly'?

I am trying to use Axios to login in my Vue SPA.

I changed everything to Vue component except for the Routes `Auth::routes();` generated by `php artisan ui:auth`. Therefore, I can no longer use `@csrf` on my forms and have to send the csrf token through the header of axios. I've tried almost everything for 2 days now until I notice that the XSRF TOKEN given to my cookies by Laravel is different from what I'm getting in my HTML... Please refer to the photos below.

This is coming from the developer tools.

[image]
[image]

> app.blade.php

I added this so i can set retrieve the CSRF token and attach it to the axios headers.

[image]

Upon console.log(), I see a different token. 
[image]

The token i get when I console.log() : `o3nQRW6IqiKdNGOdiHc59pYXXD3sBw8YfbpCPvf7`

[image]

Why don't just get the CSRF Token from the cookie then using `document.cookie`?, same thing. It doesn't match whenever I console.log().

This is definitely the reason why whatever I do, i always got a 419 error CSRF token mismatch. What could be causing this?

Note: I'm only using the `Auth::routes()` in the `api.php` file. Nothing in `web.php`. Strangely, I was able to register a user ONCE but never again due to the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say at this moment, but hopefully this helps:

---

Is your SPA outside of your Laravel application? Then I suggest to use the new Laravel Airlock package that handles the CSRF token for you. More information can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/airlock

> Laravel Airlock is renamed to Sanctum: https://blog.laravel.com/airlock-renamed-to-sanctum

If your SPA is inside your Laravel app, take a look to your axios configuration if it uses the X-CSRF-Token in the header. More information can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Q: Is your SPA outside of your Laravel application? 

A: I'm not sure how to answer this but i guess no. The SPA is inside laravel. 
I placed the vue files inside `/resources/js/components` and the vue root instance in `app.js`

Though the documentation says that by default Axios is already configured with the CSRF Token on its headers. I still went ahead with many solutions attaching the content of `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to the header. I wonder if I made a blunder in attaching to axios. btw, I'm configuring the axios that I found in `bootstrap.js` file.

Comment: Airlock looks promising. I will try to integrate it to my SPA. Thanks a lot!